# Flutter Google Places Autocomplete only for Localities and Sub Localities

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-places-api, google-places

I want to get the suggestions through Google Places API only for Localities and Sublocalities and nothing else.

I read the documentation on the Google Places Website and it seems that this is impossible. All searches also give suggestions on Provinces, Countries, Postal Codes and etc.

Please find my snippet below:

```
     void getSuggestion(String input) async {
     String kPLACES_API_KEY = "API_KEY";
    String type = '(region)';
    String baseURL =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json';
    String request =
        '$baseURL?input=$input&key=$kPLACES_API_KEY&sessiontoken=$_sessionToken&types=$type';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(request));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        _placeList = json.decode(response.body)['predictions'];
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load predictions');
    }
  }
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You can try using [Constrain place types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#constrain-place-types) of Places Autocomplete API. There, you can filter the Autocomplete API suggestions to certain [place types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table3), such as locality and sublocality.

Answer (score 0):

```
void getSuggestion(String input) async {
    String kPLACES_API_KEY = "API_KEY";
    String type = '(region)';
    String baseURL =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json';
    String request =
        '$baseURL?input=$input&key=$kPLACES_API_KEY&sessiontoken=$_sessionToken&components=country:YOUR_COUNTRY_CODE";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(request));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        _placeList = json.decode(response.body)['predictions'];
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load predictions');
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).